# Why tuple size dowsn't change after adding elements in its list element

Tags: python, list, tuples

Why both tuple7 and tuple8 have same size of 80 bytes, even after appending elements in it?

```
import sys

tuple7 = (1,2,3,[4,5])
tuple8 = (1,2,3,[4,5])
tuple8[3].append([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9])

print(tuple7, sys.getsizeof(tuple7), "bytes") # 80 bytes
print(tuple8, sys.getsizeof(tuple8), "bytes") # 80 bytes
```

Comment: you're not appending anything to `tuple8` itself, but to a list stored "inside" it. I don't know much about how Python is implemented internally but I assume `tuple8[3]` is simply a pointer, so appending elements to the list pointed at doesn't do anything to the memory representation of `tuple8` itself. As I said, I'm not certain on this but it's what I'd assume.

Comment: `getsizeof()` reports the size of Python's internal data structure. Both tuples are the same size (4 elements). If you do `sys.getsizeof(tuple7[3])` and `sys.getsizeof(tuple8[3])` you will see the effect of your `append()` call. If you want you can read the source code at https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Objects. But if I were you I would postpone doing that until you know a little more Python. You really only need to call `getsizeof()` when diagnosing performance with massive amounts of data.

Comment: Mandatory link to [Ned Batchelder](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because tuple7 and tuple8 store just reference to list ([4,5])

for understanding that try to use:

```
print(tuple7[3], sys.getsizeof(tuple7), "bytes")
print(tuple8[3], sys.getsizeof(tuple8), "bytes")
```